# Redux : update an item in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my reducer called 'reducer_product_list', I have this array :

```
let initialState = [
    {name: 'Article 1', price: 5, quantity: 10},
    {name: 'Article 2', price: 15, quantity: 8},
    {name: 'Article 3', price: 7, quantity: 15},
    {name: 'Article 4', price: 9, quantity: 5},
    {name: 'Article 5', price: 11, quantity: 100},
    {name: 'Article 6', price: 23, quantity: 20},
  ]
```

When I get the action 'ADD_TO_CART', I want to decrease the quantity of the selected object. The payload is one of those objects.

I typed the code above :

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
      initialState.map((product, i) => {
        if (product.name === action.payload.name) {
          initialState[i].quantity -= 1
          return state;
        }
      });
    default: return state
  }
}
```

If I console.log my initialState, the quantity is decreasing, but in my container that renders the view, the quantity stays the same.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
      return state.map(product => {
        if (product.name === action.payload.name) {
          return {...product, quantity: product.quantity-1}
        };
        return product;
      });
    default: return state
  }
}
```

The reason is you have to return a **new** state object derived from the current state reflecting the desired changes according to the requested action. See [Redux Reducers](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for you help, it works well! I just had to change one thing: instead of mapping on the initialState, I mapped on the state.

Comment: You need to spread the state right ? otherwise previous state will be lost right ? ideally we should never the change the redux state

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for you help, it works well!
I just had to change one thing: instead of mapping on the initialState, I mapped on the state.

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TO_CART':
      return state.map(product => {
        if (product.name === action.payload.name) {
          return {...product, quantity: product.quantity - 1}
        };
        console.log(state)
        return product;
      });
    default: return state
  }
}
```